# Unable to retrieve select input value form window.localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
   <script>

(function(window, document, undefined) {
    function changeSelect(event) {
        if(event.target.type=='checkbox' || event.target.type=='radio') {
            window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.checked?'checked':'unchecked');  
        }
        else {
            window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
        }
        if(event.target.type=='select'){
        window.localStorage.setItem(event.target.id, event.target.value);
        }
    }
    function load(event) {
        var i = 0, k, e;
        while(i < window.localStorage.length) {
            k = window.localStorage.key(i++);
            e = document.getElementById(k);
            if(e) {
                if(e.type=='checkbox' || e.type=='radio') { 
                    e.checked = window.localStorage.getItem(k)=='checked';
                }

                else {
                    e.value = window.localStorage.getItem(k);
                }
                if(e.type=='select'){
                alert('karthika');
                }

            }
        }        
    }
    function clearData(event) {
        window.localStorage.clear();
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', load, true);
    window.addEventListener('change', changeSelect, true);
    window.addEventListener('select', changeSelect, true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', changeSelect, true);
    window.addEventListener('click', changeSelect, true);
    window.addEventListener('submit', clearData, true);
})(window, document)
    </script>
```

I am storing memory of form data and retrieving it , when browser is closed suddenly or system off like this problem occur .

In the above code  i can able to retrieve  user input,textarea,checkbox .but two types values are not showing  select input and automated input values depends on other input fields

How i can able to show  select input values and auto generated values depends on user input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share fiddle of the same ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tejdeep123/4edk1t13/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For select element, you need to test the tagName property, not type property

```
if (e.tagName == 'SELECT') {
    alert('karthika');
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7tas86m5/)

Comment: yes for me now alert is coming but now no value when i test with original code